# Pandas Groupby of categorical features takes too much RAM and time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I try to understand why groupby of categorical features by panda takes too much RAM and therefore takes too much time to be executed.
Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint, randn
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat_1':randint(0,60,300000),
  'cat_2':randint(0,40,300000),
  'cat_3':randint(0,70,300000),
  'cat_4':randint(0,30,300000),
  'value':randn(300000)})
```

All the `cat_1`, ..., `cat_4` are int64 and column `value` is float. I can easily calculate the mean of column `value` using groupby command as follows:

```
df.groupby(['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4']).agg({'value':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

It takes less than a second to get this result:
[image]

If I now convert int64 columns into category and then repeat the same calculation as follows:

```
for col in ['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4']:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')

df.groupby(['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4']).agg({'value':'mean'}).reset_index()
```

I will get a wrong results (too much rows with NAN as mean value)
[image]

I use pandas==0.25.3, and Python 3.7.4.

Can anyone help me with this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try groupby with `observed=True`:

```
print(df.groupby(['cat_1', 'cat_2', 'cat_3', 'cat_4'], observed=True).agg({'value':'mean'}).reset_index())
```

**Output**

```
       cat_1 cat_2 cat_3 cat_4     value
0         33    32    46     6 -2.890154
1         33    32    46    27 -2.476471
2         33    32    46    13  0.500962
3         33    32    46    22  1.833252
4         33    32    40    12  0.666898
...      ...   ...   ...   ...       ...
291135    52     9     9    18 -0.382408
291136    52     9     9    19 -1.325040
291137    52     9    27     2 -0.025054
291138    52     9    38    23  0.652825
291139    52     9    38     7 -1.949213

[291140 rows x 5 columns]
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> observed : bool, default False
>
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False:
>   show all values for categorical groupers.
>
> New in version 0.23.0.